# Unexpected behaviour of node app (both production and development mode) after packaging (npm run dist)

Tags: node.js

I have been managing an app which use macaddress, serialport and online cryptojs library cdn. Here, macaddress doesn't work when system is not connected to internet, and app shows some cryptojs error of not getting online cdn link provided when I increase system date by nine months or more.

So I researched and found node-getmac module for getting macaddress of system offline, and installed crypto-js module to replace online cdn link. These changes work fine after `npm start`. But when I package the app using `npm run dist`, and then I use `npm start`, it shows error:

```
Uncaught Error: \\?\D:\aerosmartgas3.1.1\node_modules\@serialport\bindings\build\Release\bindings.node is not a valid Win32 application.
```

And the packaged app shows error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'crypto-js'
```

Now, after `npm install`, error is resolved for development mode (`npm start`) until `npm run dist`.

This problem is not solved even if I revert the changes in code and uninstall the new installed modules.
I also tried `npm run dist --no-prune`, but still the problem is the same.

Comment: Maybe `crypto-js` is installed as a dev-dependency in your `package.json`. Check your `package.json` to make sure crypto-js is in the list of dependencies

Comment: yes , "crypto-js": "^4.0.0" is installed as dev-dependency, if i uninstall and make proper changes in code, then it shows Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'node-getmac'. node-getmac is also installed aas dev-depencency in package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

crypto-js and node-getmac are installed as dev-dependency (due to ***npm install crypto-js --save-dev***). Just uninstalling(***npm uninstall crypto-js***) them and again install as dependency(***npm install crypto-js***) served the purpose.